# Optimización pintado, asp o ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net, json, vb.net, optimización

Llevo unos meses desarrollando una aplicación web. Hasta ahora yo siempre había pintado con los controles de asp y para evitar el load usaba update panels. Pero me he encontrado que aquí usando .net lo que hacen es llamar desde ajax a las funciones en el archivo aspx para evitar el postback.
Se me hace bastante raro, y me gustaría saber cual de las dos es mas optimo,

1. Pintar un asp:gridview en el databind
2. Pintar una tabla con una llamada ajax al aspx con respuesta JSon y pintarla con bootstrap table.

En principio, visualmente si que veo la respuesta rápida, pero la cantidad de llamadas ajax que hay que hacer..., ¿merece la pena? Es optimo usar con .Net o ¿es mejor aplicarlo con otros lenguajes como php por ejemplo?

A mi lo que me comentan es que al final tras los controles de asp termina habiendo lo mismo que hacemos a mano... ¿Entonces?

En resumen, técnicamente hablando, ¿que es mejor para la optimización en la carga de datos de una aplicación de tablas y formularios para gran cantidad de datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo diría que una de las principales desventajas esta en el peso del response del servidor, si es por comparar, al usar ajax solo haces un request al servidor y devuelves por ejemplo un objeto json (también puedes devolver html u otro tipo de dato), el cual al lado de un updatepanel que se carga como html en el servidor y no solo eso si no que también el viewstate y quien sabe que mas, hace que el response sea gigante, con esto la performance de tu aplicación también se ve perjudicada.

Si bien el uso de updatepanels hace muy simple la comunicación asyncrona con el servidor, si esta realiza muchos request seguidos, el tamaño de la data transferida es considerablemente mas grande que en el uso mas moderno con js. Por no mencionar que una vista o aspx con varios updatepanels se vuelve poco legible.

Otra ventaja para mi es que manejar directamente el javascript y el html de una pagina hace mas fácil su manipulacion ya que como mencionas los controles de aspx son finalmente wrappers de html normal, también facilita la mantencion o escalabilidad de la pagina.

Por otro lado el estándar es usar ajax hoy en dia. .NET ha estado avanzando mas en tecnologías como mvc o web api las cuales claramente están hechas para trabajar con ajax, con esto logras sacar peso de procesamiento del servidor y cambiarlo a procesamiento en el equipo del cliente. también si quieres usar librerías actuales como angular, react o vue el estándar seria comenzar a hacer peticiones ajax desde el cliente. ya sea con promesas u observables, los cuales también son avances importantes en el área de desarrollo web.

Yo use mucho tiempo UpdatePanels, hoy me doy cuenta que los use mas de lo que debía :)

te dejo un link con mas info con respecto a lo mismo.

http://lprocksit.blogspot.com/2012/05/aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-very.html

En resumen es mas optimo el uso de javascript desde el cliente.